# Golang create var while in debug

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

How can I create a `var` while in debug mode, in vs code?

what I tried:
`a = 3`
`Unable to evaluate expression: 1:3: expected '==', found '='`

`a := 3`
`Unable to evaluate expression: 1:3: expected 'EOF', found ':='`

`var a int = 3`
`Unable to evaluate expression: 1:1: expected operand, found 'var'`

Comment: Go is a compiled language, you cannot create a var on-the-fly. Did you come from Python or Javascript? Things work differently in compiled languages.

Comment: I know you can't, but maybe debug mode has some special features. debug in go is used only to view a vars value at a point in time? you cant execute anything? i might as well  just add prints in that case

Comment: You can check details on what's possible on the [vscode debug page](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/debugging#features).

Comment: There is no „debug mode“ in which Go code is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, and there would be no value in doing so. The debugger allows you to pause execution at breakpoints and inspect the state of the application at that point before continuing. It cannot modify the program while it is executing, which means defining a new variable would have no purpose since nothing could reference it anyway.